# In Terminal, where it displays XXX@YYY , what is XXX and what is YYY?

Tags: macos, terminal, user-account, migration

I transferred a backup to a new mac.  However the names got changed, and one has a `-2` added to it. Now my terminal reads `name@name-2 -$`.   In Finder it appears like so:

```
`name (2)`
  `HardDriveName`
    `Users`
       `name`
```

Trying to identify what `name (2)` is and how I can change it if possible.   Was never prompted in the migration and not sure why the `-2` is appended in the terminal now.

Comment: My guess is that the two computer were at one point both running on the same network. When this happens, one computer changes its hostname to “Name (2)” to avoid confusion and, possibly, conflicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name (2)` is your computer's hostname. You can change it in the 'Sharing' section of System Preferences:

[image: Sharing.prefPane]